# I am getting error in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

```
A1 = LOAD'/home/sawanvijay/POC/IMDB.txt';
A2 = FOREACH A1 GENERATE $0;
A3 = FOREACH A2 GENERATE TOKENIZE($0);
A4= FOREACH A3 GENERATE REPLACE($0,'([^a-zA-Z\\s]+)',' ');
A5 = FOREACH A4 GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE($0));
```

When running command:

DUMP A4;

in `Pig` showing an error:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1045: 
<line 32, column 24> Could not infer the matching function for 
   org.apache.pig.builtin.REPLACE as multiple or none of them fit. 
   Please use an explicit cast.
```

Details at **logfile**: `/home/sawanvijay/pig_1452747154040.log`

Please tell me what is the issue?

Comment: I guess you have bag of words in A3.$0, but REPLACE needs string there. Such errors are usually caused by wrong type of argument.

Comment: I agree with @zuku comments. Can you share sample test data and expected output in question ?